# Email sending using smtp server in php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

```
        <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type ="text" name="email" value="<?php echo 'email'; ?>" />
        <br>
        <button  type="submit" id='delete'    value="Truncate"><b>MailTo</b></button>       
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
         </form>
        </body>


        <?php
        require_once("./PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php");
         if(isset($_POST['submitted'])==1)
        { 

        $mail=new PHPMailer();
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        echo $email;
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug=1;
        $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure='ssl';
        $mail->Host='smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com';
        $mail->Port='465';
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Username='abc@xyz.com';
        $mail->Password='******';

        $mail->Subject='hello datastra';
        $mail->Body='this is a test mail from xyz';
        $mail->AddAddress($email,$name='xyz');
        if($mail->Send())
        {
           echo 'message sent successfully';

         }
        else
         {
           echo 'mailer error'.$mail->ErrorInfo;
         }
          }
```

I'm trying to send email to corresponding mail id but i'm failing with get error msg that

```
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 501 Syntax error in arguments
The following From address failed: root@localhost : MAIL not accepted from server,501,Syntax error in arguments

SMTP server error: Syntax error in arguments
mailer errorThe following From address failed: root@localhost : MAIL not accepted from server,501,Syntax error in arguments

SMTP server error: Syntax error in arguments

SMTP server error: Syntax error in arguments 
can anyone let me know where i'm going wrong
```

Comment: When i used with the setAddress and AddAddress with out filling form it worked but now i'm using with form filling where the EmailTo will be specified in input field

Answer (score 0):

Your error messages are quite clear. you need to set "From" attributes

```
$mail->From       = "abc@xyz.com";
$mail->FromName   = "Joe Doe";
```